# I am having some problems querying relationship within our schema using the SOAP API?

Tags: soql

```
    I am trying to query the relationship "Assigned_To__r" within the "Case" object, so I can return the Name of the User that is currently assigned to the case.I have tried many different syntaxes, and read many different web pages on this, but can't seem to figure it out. Here is my current syntax that isn't working, but as I said, I've tried many different combinations 
Please help.


`select Id,CaseNumber,Subject,(select Name from Assigned_To__r) 
from Case 
where Closure_Code__c <> 'Invalid Support Case' 
and Closure_Code__c <> 'Duplicate Case' 
and Closure_Code__c <> 'Spam''
```

This is the error I am getting:

> INVALID_TYPE: 
>   CaseNumber,Subject,(select Name from Assigned_To__r) from Case where
>   ^
>
> ERROR at Row:1:Column:48 Didn't understand relationship
>   'Assigned_To_*r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to
>   use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '*_r' after the
>   custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe
>   call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 0):

Your SOQL has a few formatting issues.

If you can clarify how the `Assigned_To__c` custom field relates to a `Case`, I can be a bit clearer in how to help solve your problem. However, based upon my best guess of your situation (specifically, `Closure_Code__c` is a standard picklist and `Assigned_To__r` is a custom child-to-parent relationship field on the `Case`), I'll wager your desired SOQL looks something like this:

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Assigned_To__r.Name
  FROM Case
 WHERE Closure_Code__c NOT IN ('Invalid Support Case', 'Duplicate Case', 'Spam')
```